# I have 5 methods which use stored procedures,i want SqlTransaction for all 5 methods at once

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have this error message:"

> When the command assigned to the command is in the pending local
>   process, ExecuteNonQuery requires the command to have a process. The
>   Command property of the command has not been initialized." I get id
>   from first method to use for other 4 methods.

this is my code;

```
SqlTransaction myTransaction;
try
{
    myconnection.Open();

    KisiBilgiKaydet();
    EgitimBilgiKaydet();
    SinavBilgiKaydet();
    ProgramBilgiKaydet();
    BelgeKaydet();
    myTransaction.Commit();
    myconnection.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    myTransaction.Rollback();
    myconnection.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put in the transaction to each SqlCommand in all methods you needed in:

```
SqlTransaction  transaction;

try
{
    myconnection.Open();
    transaction = myconnection.BeginTransaction();

    KisiBilgiKaydet(transaction);
    EgitimBilgiKaydet(transaction);
    SinavBilgiKaydet(transaction);
    ProgramBilgiKaydet(transaction);
    BelgeKaydet(transaction);
    transaction.Commit();
    myconnection.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

    transaction.Rollback();    
    myconnection.Close();
}
```

And be sure to use the transaction in the methods like:

```
private void sqlMethod(SqlTransaction transaction)
{
    var cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection, sqlTransaction);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `SqlTransaction`, then that's fine - but you need to **pass the transaction in** to each method (or otherwise make it available to them), and the code in each method needs to *explicitly use that transaction and connection*. But in principle: fine, have fun!

There *is* also *ambient transactions* aka `TransactionScope` - this is *simpler* to use, but a: doesn't work on .NET Core, and b: has a nasty habit of escalating to an MSDTC transaction (which is: bad). So personally: I'd just pass the transaction in.

Comment: @LorenzoIsidori huh, fair enough, I must have misremembered from the earlier .NET Core versions... or maybe it doesn't include the full range of scenarios (LTM/DTC/etc)? meh, it doesn't matter...